# strings over udp android

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, udp, client

I can receive data on c# UDP server i have written through this code but instead of string i have typed in the editText box ...  i receive android.widget.EditText@xxxxxx on the server. Some Help would be much appreciated.

```
package com.winmote.pro;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cmd= editText1.toString();
                new nwcomm().execute(cmd);

            }
        });
    }

    private class nwcomm extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String msg=text[0].toString();
                InetAddress to = null;
                try {
                    to = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int port=55505;
                DatagramSocket soc = null;
                try {
                    soc = new DatagramSocket();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] data = msg.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket pac = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, to, port);
                try {
                    soc.send(pac);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask for the *contents* of the EditText, not the String representation of the variable... Change this line:

```
String cmd= editText1.toString();
```

To:

```
String cmd = editText1.getText().toString();
```